# IIS 8 - Access to the Path … is Denied

Tags: browser, iis-8

I'm using iis 8 for web deployment in my network.when i'm opening in a browser it is showing access denied and i had checked all security setting.how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open up IIS Manager and check the Basic Settings of the Web App. There is a Test Settings option that will perform checks and allow you to identify issues. It could be a number of issues. More than likely, your IIS user does not have permission to access the files of the web application.